# File.Exists doesn't recognise ~ shortcut on Mac?

Tags: macos, .net-5

`File.Exists("~/Documents/test.dat")` returns false, but `File.Exists("Users/MyUser/Documents/test.dat")` returns true.

`~` is a shortcut for your home-directory `/Users/User` on MacOS, is this a bug or a documented feature that it's seemingly not supported?

Comment: `~` probably gets expanded to your user in Bash but not everywhere. You most likely want `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` (which is cross-platform, by the way)

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised it wasn't "built in"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto although curiously `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` takes you to `~` not to `~/Documents` so you have to add it.

Comment: Ah, I've never used Mac so I couldn't comment. `MyDocuments` was just a guess from my side

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it's the best option. Just a minor curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~` character is specific to the shell.  Bash, for example, has a large [set of behaviors](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) that paths that start with the `~` character can do.

When you're programming in most languages this expansion is not available as you're not in a bash (or other) shell.  Instead, I'd get the `$HOME` environment variable.  For C# it would look something like:

```
File.Exists(GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME") + "/Documents/test.dat")
```

though I haven't tested this.

**EDIT**

As indicated another possibility is to use the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-5.0) enum.  This is meant to be a cross platform helper though many of the enum's are very Windows specific.  Based on your comments the enum `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` should take you to `/Users/username/Documents` on Mac as that would be the same as `C:\Users\username\My Documents` in Windows.  But it doesn't appear to work the same.  That's a shame as it would allow for more cross-platform code.

Comment: Isn't `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.xxx` the better option?

Comment: I guess - as you indicate it's not as portable as they'd like you to believe.  I'm coming from this from a Unix perspective where you rely on the environment variables and not the enums - so many of the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enums are useless outside of Windows.

Comment: TBH if you add that as another option it's a decent answer. The main thing is that `~` is a shell shortcut rathe than a system feature